# Service Pattern - eliminating code repetition

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, design-patterns, model-view-controller

Generally, all of the services in my service layer follow the same pattern:

```
public ApiResponseDto DoStuff (int parameter){
   var response = new ApiResponseDto();
   try{
       using (var db = new DbConext()){
           // do stuff
           // throw descriptive exceptions when needed
           return response;
       }
   }
   catch (Exception e) {
       ThrowError(e) // handles logging, verbosity per environment, etc
       response.Success = false; // etc
       return response;
   }
}
```

What I'm wondering is - is there a pattern that I can use to eliminate this code repetition?  This same footprint is used ~200 times throughout the app I'm working on and it seems proper to try and reduce the repetition somehow.

Comment: Look at the `template method` pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Couple things you could try:

1. Pull out the common code into a static helper class and then use it in your controller methods
2. Create a base API controller and inherit from that

#### Option 1

...looks something like this:

```
public static class WebHelpers
{
    public static DTO GetHelper<T, DTO>(Func<T> getMethod)
    {
        T entity;
        try
        {
            entity = getMethod();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {           
            ThrowError(e); // handles logging, verbosity per environment, etc
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
        }
        if (entity == null) throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        DTO dto = Mapper.Map<DTO>(entity); // project entity to DTO using AutoMapper (or do it manually)
        return dto;
    }
}
```

And then in your API controller methods:

```
public EntityDto Get(int id)
{
    return WebHelpers.GetHelper<Entity, EntityDto>(() =>
    {
        using (var db = new DbConext())
        {           
            return db.Entities.Find(id);            
        }
    });
}
```

#### Option 2

...looks something like this:

```
public abstract class BaseApiController<T, DTO>
{
    public virtual DTO Get(int id)
    {
        T entity;
        try
        {
            using (var db = new DbConext())
            {
                entity = db.Set<T>().Find(id);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ThrowError(e); // handles logging, verbosity per environment, etc
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
        }
        if (entity == null) throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        DTO dto = Mapper.Map<DTO>(entity); // project entity to DTO using AutoMapper (or do it manually)
        return dto;
    }       
}
```

And then inherit:

```
public class EntityApiController : BaseApiController<Entity, EntityDto>
{ 
}
```

You'd have to do some fussing around with the routing if you went with option 2.